# Clicking twice to edit filename - what are the reasons for this pattern?

Tags: usability, design-patterns

Like we all know, one can edit a file or folder name in Windows Explorer by either right clicking and choosing "Rename" from the context menu OR by highlighting the file by left-clicking, and clicking once again to get into edit mode (although you have to wait a brief moment not to do a double-click).

This is a feature that confused me from the beginning of my Windows past and until recently, I have mostly been using the "Rename" option in the dialog box. Now I am using it more often, mostly because it needs fewer clicks and is easer to perform on a touchpad. But still, it doesn't feel intuitive to me, and I presume there are more that feel the same way.

Does anyone know where this pattern came from and what are its reasons in terms of usability?

[image: File rename]

Comment: I used F2 for renames, it's much faster because you don't have to wait for the second click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concept came from Apple who introduced the single button mouse in the original mouse in 1984 and it has carried on as a way to perform an additional action. To quote [this article from coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/double-click-must-die.html)

> It was basically forced on the industry by Apple Computer when they
>   elected to use a single button mouse on the original Mac in 1984.
>   Technically, double-click is an optional shortcut for clicking an
>   object and then clicking the File, Open menu; it's how you distinguish
>   between selection (pick this one) and action (launch this one).
>
> The main reason for double-click is to allow two operations to be
>   overloaded onto a single-button mouse. Designers of more recent
>   multi-button GUIs have faithfully duplicated a weaknesses that was
>   made necessary by limitations of an early single-button GUI: let's do
>   better in the future. Content applets should be particularly wary of
>   double-click since people will think of them as single-click Web
>   content. (Former Apple human evangelist Bruce Tognazzini provides
>   further details about how newer window systems copied acknowledged
>   weaknesses of the Mac in his book Tog on Software Design)

So to answer your question, it was adapted from the Mac by existing Windows systems and has become a standard despite its known usability issues.

Comment: What a great history lesson I never knew that--great link

Comment: Sounds pretty reasonable, thanks for the quick answer!